# Actionscript 3 and Flex 4 Zoom Gesture on SWFLoader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I seem to be having issue with Zoom Gestures on a SWFLoader. I have an swf file which is a floor plan of a home, I want the user to be able to zoom in and out with two finger touch, the following code below is what I tried and does not work. When I test on a touchscreen, it does not zoom when I place two fingers inside the SWF and try to zoom in.

```
<s:SWFLoader id="floorplanImage" source="@Embed('assets/test2.swf')" width="100%" height="100%" smoothBitmapContent="true" horizontalAlign="center" />
```

here is my actionscript 3 code

```
import flash.ui.Multitouch;  
            import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;  

            Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

            import flash.events.Event;

            public var selectedItem:Object;

            public function init(): void
            {
                floorplanImage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM , onZoom);
            }

            public function onZoom (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
                floorplanImage.scaleX *= e.scaleX;
                floorplanImage.scaleY *= e.scaleY; 
            }
```

Please Help!

**UPDATE**

I am going the route of gestouch, however with this code, I CANNOT zoom in or out on an SWF. With a regular image it works, but not with SWF unless I am missing something. Here is my code:

```
<mx:Script>
                <![CDATA[

                    import org.gestouch.events.GestureEvent;
                    import org.gestouch.gestures.TransformGesture;

                    private var _zoom:TransformGesture;

                    [Embed(source="assets/test2.swf")]
                    private var myClass:Class;
                    private var myMovieClip:MovieClip;


                    private function initModel():void
                    {   

                        myMovieClip = MovieClip(new myClass());
                        swfcontainer.addChild(myMovieClip);

                        _zoom = new TransformGesture(swfcontainer);
                        _zoom.addEventListener(org.gestouch.events.GestureEvent.GESTURE_BEGAN, onGesture);
                        _zoom.addEventListener(org.gestouch.events.GestureEvent.GESTURE_CHANGED, onGesture);

                    }

                    private function onGesture(event:org.gestouch.events.GestureEvent):void
                    {
                        const gesture:TransformGesture = event.target as TransformGesture;
                        var matrix:Matrix = swfcontainer.transform.matrix;

                        // Panning
                        matrix.translate(gesture.offsetX, gesture.offsetY);
                        swfcontainer.transform.matrix = matrix;

                        if (gesture.scale != 1)
                        {
                            // Scale and rotation.
                            var transformPoint:Point = matrix.transformPoint(swfcontainer.globalToLocal(gesture.location));
                            matrix.translate(-transformPoint.x, -transformPoint.y);
                            matrix.scale(gesture.scale, gesture.scale);
                            matrix.translate(transformPoint.x, transformPoint.y);

                            swfcontainer.transform.matrix = matrix;
                        }
                    }

                ]]>
            </mx:Script>

<mx:Image id="swfcontainer" horizontalAlign="center" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

When I use this with a regular image, it still does not work properly...it doesn't keep the image center when zooming, it does not let me zoom in, only out and when I first use it, it moves the image to the right. HOW COME THIS IS SOOOOOO HARD?

Please keep in mind I am very very new to Adobe Flex and Actionscript, so please make your answers as clear as possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code has no problem,I'll explain what I did for my project. Maybe it helped, i have Window design app and i load SWF into starling and have issue
with zoom and pan;

FYI: I Use starling and load SWF file with native overlay in starling and zoom pan work

```
   _mLoader = new Loader();
 var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("drawer.swf" + "?nf=" + getTimer());
_mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
 _mLoader.load(mRequest);


     private function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:flash.events.Event):void
    {
          _mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, 
           Starling.current.nativeOverlay.addChild(LoaderInfo(loadEvent.currentTarget).content);

    }
```

And because the library touching the flash was weak i use above lib,and this is to Strong

first of all test above lib maybe that's work Without Starling

[better GESTURE lib than flash lib](https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch)

my zoom code with this lib

```
     var _zoom:
    _zoom = new TransformGesture(this);
    _zoom.addEventListener(GestureEvent.GESTURE_BEGAN, onGesture);
    _zoom.addEventListener(GestureEvent.GESTURE_CHANGED, onGesture);

private function onGesture(event:org.gestouch.events.GestureEvent):void 
    {

        const gesture:TransformGesture = event.target as TransformGesture;

        var matrix:Matrix = container_movieclip.transform.matrix;



        if (container_movieclip.scaleX!=1 || container_movieclip.scaleY!=1) 
        {
            matrix.translate(gesture.offsetX, gesture.offsetY);
            container_movieclip.transform.matrix = matrix;
        }

        if (gesture.scale != 1)
        {
            var transformPoint:Point = matrix.transformPoint(container_movieclip.globalToLocal(gesture.location));
            matrix.translate(-transformPoint.x, -transformPoint.y);
            matrix.scale(gesture.scale, gesture.scale);
            matrix.translate(transformPoint.x, transformPoint.y);
            container_movieclip.transform.matrix = matrix;

        }

    }
```

I hope I could help

Comment: Hey, I looked into the library today, I am fairly new to Adobe Flex and Actionscript 3, Im trying to understand it, it will take me some time. Will doing this method, zoom in on the image only and not the whole stage and keep the image center when zooming in and out? Also I might be using a png or svg or jpg will this method work for those?

Comment: yes its work,I did something like your project with this library(keep the image center when zooming in and out),And definitely will work for PNG,But I did not try for the SVG,It must work.Examples and issues that are in GitHub helped me a lot [Examples](https://github.com/fljot/GestouchExamples)

Comment: I am having trouble installing this on my Adobe Flex project....I am using Adobe Flash Builder.

Comment: Error on the second line of code: `The this keyword can not be used in static methods. It can only be used in instance methods, function closures, and global code.`

Comment: Also I am getting errors like Access of undefined property _zoom. -Access of possibly undefined property _zoom. Access of undefined property onGesture.

Comment: Okay, I was able to work through those errors but I have a new one `Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously. flash.events:GestureEvent and org.gestouch.events:GestureEvent are available.`

Comment: So I was able to use your code....however it does not work at all for SWFLoader, however its does for Images....Do I have to do the first part of the code? The Loader code?

Comment: trying to do the first part of your code....but I got an error 'Access of possibly undefined property Starling.'

Comment: Did you add starling libraries?

Comment: for more information look at this [starling](https://gamua.com/starling/download/)

Comment: I added the starling swc file to my libraries and import starling, same error `-Access of possibly undefined property Starling.` Can you provide a full example that will work with adobe flex. That will load a swf and I am able to zoom in AND out, not just zoom out.

Comment: Okay, I imported properly...but surprise, surprise new error `-1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.display:DisplayObject to an unrelated type Function.`

Comment: Im still having the same issue as yesterday...I CANT ZOOM IN OR OUT ON A SWF.

Answer (score 1):

simply your issue solved if you changed multiinputMethod to touchpoint

```
Multitouch.inputMode=MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
```